# How to parse String vars in Java?

Tags: java, regex, parsing

What is the best way to parse a String value that looks like this `id#1 ...id#398`, so I can get de number after the `id#` String in JAVA.

Comment: replaceAll("id#", " ");

Comment: In any sort of question requiring code (a regex is technically a kind of code) it helps to show an attempt. We want to know exactly where you fell short, in order to write an answer that will help you be a better programmer and understand the task at hand a bit more, not to simply give you the answer without helping you learn about how to make one.

Comment: The best way is to show us what you've done. :)

Comment: You can also use split by "id#" and get all values to an array. depends on your needs and how you wish your final result to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `id#` is a fixed prefix in every ID, I would have used

```
stringValue.split("id#")[0]
```

Comment: Why the UNACCEPT after so long? What was this question and whats the required help?